# using viewmodel with create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model

I have a ViewModel with two models in it which works find when displaying data. My problem is I want to add a foreach() within the Create.cshtml file. Any ideas?

----Create.cshml-----

```
@model demo.Models.ViewModel

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Create Reference";}<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {    
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)    
<fieldset>
        <legend>Submission Form </legend>        

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div> 

                 <div class="editor-field">
                     <!-- iterate through ExternalContentModel and make checkboxes. -->
                    @foreach (var item in Model.ExternalContentModel)
                    {
                        <label class="checkbox">
                             <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="@item.auth_lname"> @item.auth_lname
                        </label>
                    }
                </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrganizationName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrganizationName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrganizationName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
    </div>      

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

------Controller-----

```
    //
    // GET: /Create
    public ActionResult Create() <=== can this be the problem????
    { 
        demo.Models.ViewModel vm = new demo.Models.ViewModel();            
        vm.ExternalContentModel = _repository.ExternalContent();

        // Return the content from the External Model to the Create. 
        return View(vm); 
    }

    //
    // POST: /MailingReferences/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public ActionResult Create(Reference reference) <=== can this be the problem????
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.References.Add(reference);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }             
        return View(reference);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have different models then why don't you just create a editor templates for each model?

You can do this by creating a folder called "EditorTemplates" in the same folder your Create.cshtml view lives in. Now add a view for your model into that folder. The view should be named the same as your model class. E.g. a class called FooBarModel would have an editor template called FooBarModel.cshtml.

You would then just use the editor template by doing @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FooBar)